# Choosing correct OTA

Tags: fastboot, boot, bootloader

Android OS crashed.  Error Message

```
Android Recovery
TCL/REVL_2_5052w/A30ATMO
8.1.0/OPM1.171019.011/VAR4A-0
user/release-keys
```

> Think that means 8.1.0 = Oreo API level 27

https://developers.google.com/android/ota [only lists the following in a search for 1.171019.011 ]

```
"taimen" for Pixel 2 XL
"walleye" for Pixel 2
"marlin" for Pixel XL
"sailfish" for Pixel
"ryu" for Pixel C
"angler" for Nexus 6P
"bullhead" for Nexus 5X
```

To "usb boot" device i'm following: https://www.droidwin.com/fix-cant-load-android-system-your-data-may-be-corrupt-without-reset/

it "seems" user may have held power button too long and that messed up os boot cycle somehow.  Reason to believe circumventing normal boot will allow system to reset and possibly return to normal (at least regain access to data on phone) No new apps downloaded within last 6mnths.

In order to download the OTA Images I need to know which full ota image is correct....right? or will any 1.171019.011 matching image work for the purpose of "usb booting" android?

If it was a linux os i would usb boot - regain access, hd scan, clear caches/temp files and track down the one or two corrupt files preventing boot.  Not sure correct way to achieve this on android.

---

Many blogs about fixing boot load error have  a boot menu
1.Reboot system now

2. Reboot to bootloader
3. Apply update from ADB
4. Apply update from SD card
5. Wipe data/factory reset
6. Mount/system
7. View recovery logs
8. Run graphics test
9. Run locale test

10.Power off

This phone is only displaying boot options

1. try again

2 Wipe data/factory re-test

---

`adb version`

> Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41

> Version 33.0.2-8557947

> Installed as /media/k/platform-tools/adb

`adb devices`

> List of devices attached

---

Device: https://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/b6604de0

Comment: Before attempting to flash anything, we need to know the specific device model because Android images are not universal. It's not possible to flash Pixel's image to non-Pixel devices, or even one Pixel image to another different Pixel device (it might even brick the device if something wrong happens badly).

Comment: didnt know if REVL_2_5052w was the model, but it is a Revvl 2 tmobil.  Error msg in op only info available because boot load returning error message, and can not remove back of phone.